# Is a PChar UTF-8 coded?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, character-encoding, pascal

I'm writing a tool, which use a C-DLL. The functions of the C-DLL expect a `char*`, which is in UTF-8 Format.
My question: Can I pass a `PChar` or do I have to use `UTF8Encode(string)`?

Comment: You should pass a `PByte` or `PAnsiChar` ensuring that the target is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: What's your Delphi version?

Comment: I have to write it in Pascal, which is supports all types of Pascal (Delphi, GNU Pascal, Free Pascal) and so on

Comment: that means that you have to make a table for yourself:
what are different versions of Delphi/FPC/GP/all other pascal implementations do exists. How you program can detect those versions ? which abilities to transcode to UTF8 do exist in those versions. And then make a code for every of those compilers/versions.  You may try to use Jedi CodeLib (jcl.sf.net), but there is no official support for latest FPC and GP was never supported. Also there is no support for PaxScript Pascal, Oxygen, MIDlet Pascal, Virtual Pascal and so forth.

Comment: What about the standard Pascal, the one that was specified in 1974, there was no UTF8 in it, no C and no DLL. And i son;t remember if there even were strings. You cannot even formulate your task in "Standard Pascal" terms. So like it or not, but you have to make a list of compilers and versions that you gonna support, and then ask for implementation for every given compiler/version. "All types of Pascal" is not a term that have any real sense behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a string variable named `s`. On an ANSI Delphi `PChar(s)` is ANSI encoded. On a Unicode Delphi it is UTF-16 encoded.

Therefore, either way, you need to convert `s` to UTF-8 encoding. And then you can use `PAnsiChar(...)` to get a pointer to a null terminated C string.

So, the code you need looks like this:

```
PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(s))
```

Comment: I've answered the question for Delphi since the question is tagged Delphi. If you really want answers for all flavours of Pascal, that's more than one question.

Comment: ...or perhaps you can do `SetCodePage(s, TEncoding.UTF8.CodePage, True)`

Comment: @Arioch'The That would not help at all. The code in the answer is the canonical way to do it.

Comment: i am rather sceptical about "canon" whatever you might call it. Actually the "canonical" - in other words most quoted in forums -  form is `s := UTF8Encode(s); C_DLL_CALL(s);` and Delphi auto-converts string to PChar. THAT was canonical ever - and then one day it suddenly got broken. I believe that you should either totally rely on automagic, or make it totally disabled. Or you are aiming and surprises with each new compiler/RTL brand and version.

Comment: That code has never compiled. The code in my answer is the canonical and correct way to solve this problem, and has always been thus.

Comment: It's never compiled because it's always been wrong. It yields: E2010 Incompatible types: 'PAnsiChar' and 'RawByteString'

Comment: Sorry, David, when it was canon and One True Way there was no such type as RawByteString and there could not be such error; please, think outside of Delphi XE3

Comment: It doesn't compile in Delphi 6 either. It has never compiled in any version of Delphi.

Comment: Delphi 2007 (and probably earlier) had `UTF8Encode` which returned a `UTF8String` which was a ANSI string type (`UTF8String = type string;`). So this also works in earlier versions. +1

Comment: BTW: Delphi 2009+ also has a `UTF8String` type which uses the new code page feature, so a not backwards compatible option would be `PAnsiChar(UTF8String(s))`. In D2007 and older this would only work if the string was already UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please edit the question and add the tag with your target Delphi version.
2. Pass it as `PAnsiChar`; PChar is a joker and may mean different data types. When you work with DLL-like API, you ignore compiler safety net and that means you should make your own. And that means you should use real types, not jokers, the types that would not change no matter which compiler settings and version would be active.
3. But before getting passing the pointer you should ensure that the source data is encoded in UTF8 actually.

.

```
Var data: string; buffer: UTF8String; buffer_ptr: PAnsiChar;
Begin
   buffer := data + #0; 
 // transcoding to UTF8 from whatever charset it was, transparently done by Delphi RTL
 // last zero to ensure that even for empty string you would have valid pointer below
   buffer_ptr := Pointer(@buffer[1]); // making sure there can be no codepage bound to the datatype
   C_DLL_CALL(buffeR_ptr);
End;
```

Comment: Why are you adding the null-terminator manually? Now your string has two. You can just do `buffer := data; C_DLL_CALL(PAnsiChar(buffer))`

Comment: Because i want to supress all automation here. I am not sure if Pointer(buffer) would ensure terminator. And i am not sure that PAnsiChar(buffer) would not today or tomorrow ensure transcoding, just as AnsiString implies. P***Char are not atomic types, they are heavy loaded with compiler magic. Since there is no PUTF8Char type in RTL, to make code future-compatible i prefer to de-tooth all possible unexpecteed automation sources. Can you warranty that PAnsiChar(some-string) would never ever transcode the datatype ?

Comment: `PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(s))` is guaranteed to do what is needed.

Comment: I hope so, but i cannot see the contract, that PansiChar typecast would NEVER today and in future cause yet another transcoding. And i saw a lot of people bitten with Delphi automation where they thought there would be none. Including people who tried to detect XML source charset and apply transcoding after they got data from MSXML, they just thought that the data can not be transcoded inside and kept applying redundant transformations. Unless the PAnsiChar typecast is oficially claimed to never ever been able to cause any data transformations but terminating zero, is it not future-proof.

Comment: There's never a contract guaranteed for future as yet unreleased versions of software. So, forget all about that. What `PAnsiChar` does  today is documented.

Comment: there is a contract that `i+1 = Succ(i)`, and that `''+'a' = 'a';` and all other things remaining withing "pure pascal" before you interface with outer world and its binary details. And - i forgot that detail in original code - there is a contract that raw `pointer` is just a pointer never going to outsmart the developers. Yes, my code would rather often add extra zero char, not a big deal. But i am sure it will never broke. Having to deal with a lot pre-Unicode code that suddenly works no more because "today is documented" and future is not 2b considered, i'd prefer to be redundant but safe.

Comment: I am sure that your code is not broken. I am sure that my variant is not broken.

Comment: you code is not broken *today* with *Delphi version you work now*. Just like `s := Utf8Encode(s); C_DLL_Call(s);` did work for ages and was a "canonical" code. Those both codes share the same merits and risks. And in my eyes risks outweight their merits.

Comment: That code doesn't work and never did. You only have to compile it to see that is so. `C_DLL_Call` receives `PAnsiChar`, and `s` is `string`.

Comment: Pansichar casts are slightly dangerous because a pansichar() cast can trigger a 2 byte to 1 byte (unicodestring->ansistring) conversion using a temp, which is by default OEM, thus mutilating the string. The examples are mostly ok (using encode), but it is dangerous to do this large scale.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort In which scenario do you get UnicodeString -> AnsiString conversion? If you write `PAnsiChar(MyUnicodeStringVar)` then there is no encoding conversion. There is no local. You just get a pointer to the first character of `MyUnicodeStringVar`.

Comment: I never tested that, but if that is true, that is even scarier, since I didn't expect a pointer to a 1-byte type and a 2 byte string type to be compatible. I can't easily test, I left my Delphi running laptop at the office.

Comment: @Marco It's not really any different from casting PInteger to PDouble.

Comment: That is what i am talking about. P***Char has quite a lot of special context bound to it, quite a load of compiler magic, so people tend to be wary about it and make wrong assumptions. I think that re-using PChar for C-string in "pointer with benefits" mode was a bad design choice in long term.

Comment: @Arioch'The Sure, it has magic. And if you don't understand the magic then you can get it wrong. If you don't understand the magic, then a magic free approach like yours is certainly safe. But not so nice to work with.

Comment: @David people who used AnsiString for raw byte buffer did understood the magic. But the magic rules are not stable and in 2009 they changed. Surely if all they did was "write and forget" they did not care. But for anyone maintaining that code - it vecane a problem. For example stock `TDataSet.Bookmark` was that `AnsiString` magic. The problem for me is not how that would behave today, but how that would behave tomorrow.

Comment: PXXXXChar() magic did not change in D2009. If you disagree can you give clear evidence.

Comment: It may change later. in D2007 people also argued that "AnsiString  did not changed and are best container for raw binary data"

Comment: Anything may change. You said that `PAnsiChar` magic changed in D2009. Are you now retracting that assertion?

Comment: right above i said about AnsiString and string-related magic, or give the exact quotation

Comment: You mean where you said *In D2007 people also argued that "AnsiString did not changed and are best container for raw binary data"*

Comment: Yes, i said about AnsiString, and you started talking about PxxxxChar which is different typew from AnsiStirng. I can't understand your point.